# List of supported Places types

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get a list of the supported Places types for the places service in the Maps Javascript API. The docs refer to a link here https://developers.google.com/places/place-id/supported_types but its coming up as a dead link.

Anyone got a working link they can share please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link worked for me, hope it helps.

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types