# I have read that "Google Places API offers filtering over 100 different types".What are the different types?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I read on this link [developers google](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2012/05/google-places-api-search-refinements-as.html).But currently it does not display which are the different 100 types(that link is not working).Is there any filtering by cities or zipcode??

Comment: Ah, it looks like this was asked recently and put on hold. In any case it would be good to contact Google and inform them about the broken link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258156/list-of-supported-places-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be the [list of types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=postal_code&sensor=false&key=API_KEY so inorder to get postal_code i think types wouldnt help but is listed in "Additional types returned by the Places service".So how to use it??

Comment: The `API_KEY` value in that request isn't set, so the result is invalid.

Comment: no i have given it,but no results.In that link it says "The types below are not supported in the types filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place."